# getEncryptedData(String) invokes inefficient new String(String) constructor - Findbugs

Tags: android, findbugs, spotbugs

I'm trying to convert byte[] to String.and its working fine. But FindBugs is pointing me a Minor issue in my code snippet.

**code snippet:**

```
        //Encrypt the data withe public key.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRASFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        encryptedData = new String(Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

**Findbug Report:**

getEncryptedData(String) invokes inefficient new String(String) constructor

**In which line i'm getting this Error?**

```
encryptedData = new String(Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Could some one please brief me what is this exactly? And how can we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
encryptedData = new String(Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

with

```
encryptedData = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Encode to String is already returning the string.